# User comments on documentation with JSDuck?

Tags: javascript, extjs, documentation-generation, jsduck

[JSDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck) offers user feedback in the generated documentation. Sencha uses this on their code doumentation. It is described in a [blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/commenting-on-documentation).

I would like to use that commenting feature for our development team too.

Who knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

JSDuck now has the commenting feature available as a different project...
https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck-comments

Answer (score 0):

JSduck itself can be used if you want to do something along those lines...
https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck